# Django Selenium Test Facebook Login

Tags: python, django, facebook, selenium

I'm using Selenium to test my Django app's ability to login via Facebook. This works when running my development server (localhost:8000), but not when running the automated test.

When running the automated test, I can get the following error:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

I believe this is because LiveServerTestCase is running a test server on port 8081.

Is there a way to configure this such that I can login with both localhost:8000 and 8081? If not, I could always just create another FB app for testing.

Comment: test code and stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: No way to configure both of these. I would suggest that you create a test app off your main app which can configure for the new port for testing. You can find out more about test apps here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps